# Why shall the spectral radius of a finite Toeplitz matrix not converge to its infinite counterpart?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius, toeplitz-matrices

I encountered this problem when studying [Spectral Properties of bounded Toeplitz Matrices](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898717853) by Bottcher & Grudsky.

For each polynomial $a=\sum_{n}a_n t^{n}$ which is in Wiener algebra, we define its corresponding infinite Toeplitz matrix, whose $j,k$ entry is:

$$T(a)_{j,k}=a_{j-k}$$

and the finite matrix $T_{N}(a)$ is the upper left $N \times N$ block in $T(a)$. The spectrum of $A$ is given by all $\lambda$ s.t. $A - \lambda I$ is not invertible. The spectral radius of $A$, $rad A$, is given by the largest $|\lambda|$ which is in the spectrum of $A$.

In section 10.3, it is stated that the spectral radius of a finite Toeplitz matrix will not converge to its infinite counterpart, e.g. for $b=t$, $rad T(b)=1$ and $rad T_{N}(b)=0$ for any $N$.

How can this be understood? In particular, I hope to know why $T(b) - \exp(i\theta)I$ is not invertible for some $\theta$.

The matrix is given by

$T_{3}(b)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

and diagonally extends infinitely for the infinite version.

It can however easily been shown that $T(b^{-1})=T(1/t)$ has eigenvalue 1:

$T(1/t)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots\\
\end{pmatrix}$

since $(1,1,1,1,...)^{T}$ is such an eigenvector. This does not work for $b=t$ though. Could Bottcher & Grudsky be making a mistake here?